# Implement LiteSync on Django

Tags: django, sqlite, synchronization, integration

I've tried to write sync sqlite database between 2 different Server but same app and DB. But when i turn on litesync.io in console, it doesnt synchronize the Django project with Django project in another server. I know it's wrong because i must configure it first in django project, but i've tried to change NAME of DATABASES into URI and it not work. I've tried it in console to execute query, it works, but not in Django Project. So, how to implement litesync on Django project? How to save data into Sqlite DB by URI?